# bcp command in SQL Server not generating full data in Excel

Tags: sql-server, excel, bcp

I have to generate a report in Excel via a SQL Server Agent job and `bcp` command. Every column data is exported correctly, except for some data in one of the columns.

I have a column called `Invoice Number` and some of the data in it is like
`00001234` or `000736`. Now when the final Excel file is generated via `bcp` command, it showing as `1234` and `736`.

Issue is with the leading `0`'s - they are not showing in the generated Excel.
Does anyone have any solution for this? Thanks

Comment: It seems the values are exported as **numbers** where leading `0` are not relevant - you need to export them as **strings** instead.

Comment: but i used convert(nvarchar(500),InvoiceNumber) in the select statement. But still it is not coming

Comment: You might need to define a [format file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/create-a-format-file-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) for your `bcp` export

Comment: If the value has already (explicitly/implicitly) been converted to a numerical datatype, converting it back won't do anything, @ANKANNASKAR . `SELECT CONVERT(varchar(5),CONVERT(int,'00001'));` returns `'1'`, not `'00001'`). Though I would not be surprised if Excel is being "clever" and seeing that value and setting the columns format to a numerical format. If it's a CSV, check the value in a text editor, not Excel. If it's a Excel file, check the actual value of the cell, not the displayed one. Alternatively, in your template file, set the column to be a `text` value, then Excel isn't "clever"

Comment: In Excel click "open special" and select the column formats. Excel can be funny about trying to work out column types automatically

Comment: actually my main table has the InvoiceNumber field as nvarchar(max) Now i am exporting data from a view which has many other tables including the main table into excel file with bcp command. In that case how do i create the format file and where do I place it

Comment: Larnu - Can you please explain what template file you are referring to here and how do i set the column to be text value

Comment: If you open your exported file with Notepad/Notepad++/your-favourite-editor I expect that you'll see all of the leading zeros are intact. When opening text/CSV files Excel tries to be "smart" and guess the data types of columns - anything that looks numeric will get leading zeros removed at display time.

Answer (score 0):

MS Excel has no notion of data types. It has cells and their visual format.

Your scenario is usually handled by concatenation of a single quote and the string with the leading zeros in the SQL statement.

char(39) will produce a single quote.

Along the following:

```
SELECT char(39) + InvoiceNumber, ... 
FROM ...;
```

Comment: This works but i get a single quote in the value like '0001234 but i want 0001234.

Comment: @ANKANNASKAR, It is peculiarity of MS Excel. That's exactly how you need to handle numeric values with leading zeros.